# OpMode stuck in stop() Android studio

Tags: java, android

We are making a parking code for FTC Skystone where a color sensor is looking for a change in hue value to stop the robot. It works most times, but if we press the stop button, the code continues and errors out with an OpMode is stuck in stop().

Other than that, The sensor will only read it four out of five times, and we have no clue of what else to do to get this to work. 
Here is our code:

```
@Override
public void runOpMode(){

    // Drive train initialization
    motorFrontRight = hardwareMap.dcMotor.get("FR");
    motorFrontLeft = hardwareMap.dcMotor.get("FL");
    motorBackLeft = hardwareMap.dcMotor.get("BL");
    motorBackRight = hardwareMap.dcMotor.get("BR");

    motorFrontLeft.setDirection(DcMotor.Direction.FORWARD);
    motorFrontRight.setDirection(DcMotor.Direction.REVERSE);
    motorBackLeft.setDirection(DcMotor.Direction.FORWARD);
    motorBackRight.setDirection(DcMotor.Direction.REVERSE);

    // Color sensor initialization
    sensorColor = hardwareMap.get(ColorSensor.class, "color_sensor");
    color2 = hardwareMap.get(ColorSensor.class, "color2");
    sensorDistance = hardwareMap.get(DistanceSensor.class, "color_sensor");

    // Color Sensor Values
    float hsvValues[] = {0F, 0F, 0F};
    final float values[] = hsvValues;.
    final double SCALE_FACTOR = 255;

    telemetry.addData("Status: ", "Initialized");
    telemetry.addData(">", "Press Play to start op mode");
    telemetry.update();
    waitForStart();

    while (opModeIsActive()){
        // Color Sensor Code

        Color.RGBToHSV((int) (color2.red() * SCALE_FACTOR),
                (int) (color2.green() * SCALE_FACTOR),
                (int) (color2.blue() * SCALE_FACTOR),
                hsvValues);
        Color.RGBToHSV((int) (sensorColor.red() * SCALE_FACTOR),
                (int) (sensorColor.green() * SCALE_FACTOR),
                (int) (sensorColor.blue() * SCALE_FACTOR),
                hsvValues);

        // Send the info back to driver station using telemetry function.
        telemetry.addData("Step: ", step);
        telemetry.addData("Hue", hsvValues[0]);
        telemetry.update();

        // Move forward
        if (step == 0){
            motorFrontRight.setPower(.2);
            motorFrontLeft.setPower(.2);
            motorBackLeft.setPower(.2);
            motorBackRight.setPower(.2);
        }

        // Does it see the line?
        while (step == 0){
            if (opModeIsActive()){
                Color.RGBToHSV((int) (sensorColor.red() * SCALE_FACTOR),
                        (int) (sensorColor.green() * SCALE_FACTOR),
                        (int) (sensorColor.blue() * SCALE_FACTOR),
                        hsvValues);
                Color.RGBToHSV((int) (color2.red() * SCALE_FACTOR),
                        (int) (color2.green() * SCALE_FACTOR),
                        (int) (color2.blue() * SCALE_FACTOR),
                        hsvValues);

                // Send the info back to driver station using telemetry function.
                telemetry.addData("Step: ", step);
                telemetry.addData("Hue", hsvValues[0]);
                telemetry.update();
            }
            if (hsvValues[0] > 150 ){ // Checks if it is red or blue
                step++;
            }
        }

        if (step == 1){
            motorFrontRight.setPower(0);
            motorFrontLeft.setPower(0);
            motorBackLeft.setPower(0);
            motorBackRight.setPower(0);
            step++;
        }

        if (step == 2){
            motorFrontRight.setPower(-.5);
            motorFrontLeft.setPower(-.5);
            motorBackLeft.setPower(-.5);
            motorBackRight.setPower(-.5);
            sleep(200);
            step++;
        }

        if (step == 3){
            motorFrontRight.setPower(0);
            motorFrontLeft.setPower(0);
            motorBackLeft.setPower(0);
            motorBackRight.setPower(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured out through the FTC forum to 
`while (step == 0){
            if (opModeIsActive()){`

to

```
while (step == 0 && opModeIsActive()){
```